# Declare object item as an Input()

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
  fruits = {
    orange: @Input() as any //gives an error
  }
```

Or is this the only way?

```
  @Input() orange!:any;

  fruits = {
    orange:this.orange
  }
```

Comment: It's a decorator. It is not intended to be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. But the answer is Yes, You can do what you are trying to do.

[Here is a working demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-whjz9r?file=src%2Fapp%2Forange.component.ts)

### Fruit Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fruit',
  template: `{{fruits | json}}`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class FruitComponent  {
  @Input() fruits: any;
}
```

### OrangeComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'orange',
  template: `
    <fruit [fruits]="fruits"></fruit>
  `
})
export class OrangeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() orange: any;
  fruits: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fruits = {
      orange: this.orange
    };
  }
}
```

### Caller Component

```
<orange orange="some Value"></orange>
```